# MySQL Query adding another condition

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT photos.*
FROM photos
INNER JOIN follows
ON photos.userid=follows.followingid
WHERE follows.followerid = $myId
ORDER BY photos.id
DESC LIMIT 10
```

How would I add an extra condition to this correctly so that it can check for photos by that user's ID (using the $myId variable)?

**UPDATE:** Now added the conditional in the syntax provided in an answer, but only shows images from users you're following not your own photos though.

**UPDATE 2:** Table structures:

[image: Table: photos]

[image: Table: follows]

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected output.  After reading your problem it's not very clear how your tables are structured.

Comment: So right now you get the photos followed by the user with id = $myID, and you want what? all photos by that user plus the photos he follows?  **EDIT**: I think @john500 has it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is difficult to gather how your tables are set up, but this may be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT photos.*
FROM photos
LEFT OUTER JOIN follows
ON photos.userid=follows.followingid
WHERE follows.followerid = $myId OR photos.userid = $myId
ORDER BY photos.id
DESC LIMIT 10
```

EDIT: I see what you're trying to do, you need to do a left outer join to include every result from the photos table, this should work.

Comment: Could you possible try to help me further here? It's not returning any results infact when I have ran it with the data in the field. There is a photo in the photos table with the userid of 1 and a user with that ID in the users table too to correspond, however my query doesn't return anything

Comment: As I stated in my question, it is a little unclear how your tables are set up and what you're trying to do. If you could edit your original post with more information like: more code, more database information, what you're attempting to do in the big picture, etc, we could help you out more.

Comment: Added images of the table structures for photos and follows, I left out users as it only requests the user id from the column "id". I am just trying to print out this data in a loop via PHP onto my web page with this query which is pretty self explanatory so I don't feel as if I would need to post the PHP code too.

Comment: I updated my answer, I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that is absolutely perfect!!